# Как лучше вывести значение переменной?Заносить ли ссылку с присвоением в тип bool

Tags: java

```
DataOnly dataOnly = new DataOnly();

boolean bool = dataOnly.aBoolean = false; // first example
System.out.println(dataOnly.aBoolean = false); //second example
```

Answer (score 1):

System.out.println(" " + bool)

Comment: Я имел в ввиду можно сразу с помощью System.out.println(......), или запихнуть в переменную а потом вывести?

Comment: Можно коречнож.но лучше всегда присваивать переменным.код очтпвдяй чистым

Comment: Поэтому сделай как я показал пихай в буль а потов выводи уже буль

Comment: Пальчик вверх ответ за +) если что пиши ещё и запомни  главне оставляй чистым код.и узнац про логирование а то систем аут принт он не для этого))))